# akka sending a closure to remote actor + Error in sending messages (case class) between Scala Akka remote actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

New query: I am trying to pass DSum() as parameter to RemoteActor from localActor, DSum() will do some calculation at Remote node. I am unable to send this to RemoteActor. IS it possible ??(code below)

Done:I am trying to connect Remote actor and local actor, and trying to send objects using case class, but it is unable to get the Message class ( Common.Message(msg) ) of the RemoteActor when being called from localActor, instead it is getting "case _ => println("Received unknown msg from local ")"

```
 1.package.scala

package object check {
    trait Context
    case object Start
    case class Message(msg: String)
    case class CxtDA(cxtA: List[CxtA])
    case class RCxt(var cxtA: List[CxtA], var cxtB: List[CxtB], var v1: Int, var v2: String) extends Context
    case class CxtA(var cxtC: List[CxtC], var v1: Int) extends Context
    case class CxtB(var cxtC: List[CxtC], var v1: Int) extends Context
    case class CxtC(var v1: String, var v2: Int) extends Context
    case class Task(var t1: DSum()) 

}


2. Remote Actor

package com.akka.remote

import java.io.File

import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import check._

/**
 * Remote actor which listens on port 5150
 */


class RemoteActor extends Actor {

    override def toString: String = {
        return "You printed the Local";
    }
    def receive = {
    case msg: String => {
      println("remote received " + msg + " from " + sender)
      sender ! "hi"
    }
    case Message(msg) =>
        println("RemoteActor received message "+ msg)
        sender ! Message("Hello from server")

    case CxtDA(cxtA) =>
        println("cxtA "+ cxtA)

    case Task(taskA) =>
            println ("recieved closure")


    case _ => println("unknown msg")
  }
}



object RemoteActor{


   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     //get the configuration file from classpath
    val configFile = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("remote_application.conf").getFile
    // //parse the config
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFile))
    // //create an actor system with that config
    val system = ActorSystem("RemoteSystem" , config)
    // //create a remote actor from actorSystem
     val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActor], name="remote")
     println("remote is ready")
    remoteActor ! Message("Hello from active remote")

   }
 }


3.Local Actor

package com.akka.local

import java.io.File

import akka.actor.{Props, Actor, ActorSystem}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import check._
import scala.util.Random

/**
 * Local actor which listens on any free port
 */
trait CxtTask {
    type CxtT <: Context
    def work(ctx: CxtT): CxtT
}


class DSum extends CxtTask with Serializable{
  override type CxtT = CxtA
    def work(ctx: CxtA): CxtA = {
    val sum = ctx.cxtC.foldRight(0)((v, acc) => v.v2 + acc)
    ctx.cxtC= List()
    ctx.v1 = sum
    println("ctx: " + ctx)
    ctx

  }
}

class LocalActor extends Actor{ 
    // import Common._

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
    val  remoteActor = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/remote")
    println("That 's remote:" + remoteActor)
    remoteActor ! "hi"
    var counter = 0  

    override def toString: String = {
        return "You printed the Local";
    }

  def receive = {   

    case msg:String => {
      println("got message from remote" + msg)
    }
    case Start =>
        println("inside Start.local "+ remoteActor)
        remoteActor ! Message("Hello from the LocalActor")


    case Message(msg) =>
         println("LocalActor received message: "+ msg)
        if (counter < 5) {
            sender ! Message("Hello back to you")
            counter += 1
        }

    case CxtDA(cxtA) =>
            remoteActor ! CxtDA(cxtA)

    case Task(t1) =>
            remoteActor ! Task(t1)


  }
}


 object LocalActor {

   def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val configFile = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("local_application.conf").getFile
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFile))
    val system = ActorSystem("ClientSystem",config)
    val localActor = system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor], name="local")
    localActor ! Start

    def createRndCxtC(count: Int):List[CxtC] = (for (i <- 1 to count) yield CxtC(Random.nextString(5), 3)).toList

    def createRndCxtB(count: Int): List[CxtB] = (for (i <- 1 to count) yield CxtB(createRndCxtC(count), Random.nextInt())).toList

    def createRndCxtA(count: Int): List[CxtA] = (for (i <- 1 to count) yield CxtA(createRndCxtC(count), Random.nextInt())).toList

    val tree = RCxt(createRndCxtA(2),createRndCxtB(2),1,"")
    val workA = new DSum()
    tree.cxtA.foreach(ctxa =>workA.work(ctxa))
    localActor ! Task(new DSum())
  }
}

[Remote actor output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtmvU.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried printing "_". What does it show?

Comment: well I tried now but it is not able to compile " case _ => println(_) " for RemoteActor.scala

Comment: You cannot print the message using the wildcard itself ( the wildcard is intended for replacing something that it is not used, hence you are contradicting its use cases). Just put `case msg => println(msg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here is that you have defined two different protocols for each actor:

- `Common` object that resides in the `RemoteActor.scala` file
- `Common` object that resides in the `LocalActor.scala` file

Hence, when sending a `Common.Message` within the Local Actor, you are basically creating a message with a different type than the `Common.Message` from the Remote Actor. Hence, the actor is not able to process it.

As a good practice in Akka, whenever an actor has a specific message procotol, that should be defined in its companion object. However, if you have multiple actors that share the same protocol (their behavior is defined by processing those types of messages), then you should put that protocol in an object and import it from your actors.

I hope this is helpful.